# Tomcat 404 не может найти index.html

Tags: java, веб-программирование, tomcat

Идиотизм. Злюсь очень.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все по туториалам. После запуска - 404 - не может найти index

Comment: Как минимум, если где-нибудь в настройках не сказано обратное, папка `web` должна называться `webapp` и лежать в `src/main`

Comment: Все сгенерилось идеей, - - - >add framework support